# NSDateFormatter returns a date off by a day

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsdateformatter

In my iPhone app, I am trying to get the EEE MMM dd from a date string received by a web service.

For all dates where time is < 07:00, the NSDateFormatter returns a date off by 1 day. For example: Date to format: 2010-11-17T05:00:00, formatted date result: Tue Nov 16

Here's the code snippet:

`NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"EEE MMM dd"];`

NSDate *dateToFormat = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:dateStringToFormat locale:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]];

NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateToFormat];
[dateFormat release];

What could be the problem?

Comment: Where do you live, and which timezone does the web service use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably has something to do with time zones.  You probably need to set an appropriate value for the timeZone property of your NSDateFormatter object.

Comment: Hmm, so I set the time zone property to be the localTimeZone. But the result is still the same. It works when the time is more than 7am. But anything before that, causes the date to go back by a day.

Comment: This was the fix: [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue but only after updating to iOS4. My formatter is like this:

> [aDateFormatter
>   setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
>   z"];

and my dates like this:

> 2009-10-27 7:30:12 -0700

I managed to fix the issue just by moving the date picker mode set **before** applying the max/min/selected date to the date picker. In my case this:

> aDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;